# Problem involving primitive root mod prime

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, primitive-roots

For positive integers $n$, let $s(n)$ be the sum of $n$-th powers of primitive roots $\bmod 1601$. Find the number of positive integers $n < 1000$ such that $1601$ divides $s(n)$.

How do I approach this problem? $3$ is the smallest primitive root of $1601$, but I am not sure how to find $s(n)$ from the same since there are $600+$ primitive roots? It's a problem I'm trying to solve

One idea I have that I'm presently working on is considering $(p-n)^{k}$ a multiple of $1601$ (obviously) and its binomial expansion, but new ideas are welcome!

Comment: Is this to be solved with paper and pencil?

Comment: Probably not using brute force, because that would be hellish. But yes, paper and pencil.

Comment: Is this a textbook exercise or a part of bigger problem which you are working on? Please add more context and your own ideas / possible approach to the problem. Also not sure why the peculiar number $1601$ is used.

Comment: First note that there is more than one primitive root (not "the" primitive root), so we have to choose one, say $g$. Once we do, here's a hint: $s(n) = g+g^2+\cdots+g^n = g(g^n-1)/(g-1)$.

Comment: @Greg Martin sadly s(n) is the sum of nth powers of single primitive roots of 1601, that is, the sum of (g_1)^n+(g_2)^n+...(g_m)^n where (g_i) is the ith primitive root mod n

Comment: So, The OP just mentions "It's a problem I'm trying to solve" and didn't address Paramanand's question. Meanwhile, there was a question also posted 3 days ago, [now deleted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4088526/how-do-i-solve-this-question-on-primitive-roots/), but used to [look like this](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:YhkMYC8iiskJ:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4088526/how-do-i-solve-this-question-on-primitive-roots/4088533+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=ch). So, which math-contest is this problem from?